# Not able to delete a file after File.WriteAllBytes()

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am trying to write byte array to a file and sending it as email. After that I need to delete the file from the saved location.

But while deleting, it throws the error

> 'The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being
> used by another process.'

As per the `File.WriteAllBytes()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllBytes_System_String_System_Byte___), it Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten. Pls help me to find a solution.

```
string FolderPath = MyPath + "PaySlips";
string filePath = FolderPath + "/" + userID + "-PaySlip_" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text + "_" + ddlYear.SelectedItem.Text + ".pdf";

if (!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
}

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
                
ArrayList attachments = new ArrayList();
attachments.Add(filePath);
SendEmail(emailID, cc, attachments);

if (File.Exists(attachments[0].ToString())) {
  File.Delete(attachments[0].ToString()); //exception happens here
}
```

'''

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: 1) Are you sure the email sending is not asynchronous and still running? 2) could this be a case of antivirus holding on to the file for a few (milli)seconds?

Comment: Also, why are you using `attachments[0].ToString()` and not just `filePath`? Is this the same method?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Both paths are same

Comment: @Mureinik Error: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: To me you may be focusing in the wrong direction, I find it more probable another unrelated thing getting a lock on the file. To narrow down the problem, let me ask... Does the problem go away if you comment the `SendEmail(emailID, cc, attachments);` line?

Comment: @Cleptus Yes, then I am able to delete the file without exception

Comment: This means that `SendMail` somehow keeps a lock on the file. What does that method do? Does it open a stream without a `using`? Is it an async method that isn't getting awaited?

Comment: I got the solution, disposed the MailMessage object and SmtpClient object

Comment: If you use the ancient SmptClient class you should keep in mind that Microsoft [strongly warns against its use in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks), suggesting people use MailKit instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Thanks @Cleptus
File.WriteAllBytes() is already closed and in the SendMail(), it's got opened again. So by disposing those objects, it worked

The SendEmail() method in my code has

```
SmtpClient smC= new SmtpClient();
 MailMessage mM= new MailMessage();
```

I added dispose of SMTPClient and MailMessage in finally block

```
try
            {
                smC.Send(mM);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Err = ex.Message;
            }
            finally {
                mM.Dispose();
                smC.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, using the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) would handle for you the `Dispose()` call of those `IDisposable` objects so you do have no need to manually dispose them.

Answer (score 1):

`string FolderPath = MyPath + "PaySlips";`
`string filePath = FolderPath + "/" + userID + "-PaySlip_" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text + "_" + ddlYear.SelectedItem.Text + ".pdf";`

```
 if (!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
        }

        

       File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
             File.Close();
                File.Dispose();
                

                ArrayList attachments = new ArrayList();
                attachments.Add(filePath);
                SendEmail(emailID, cc, attachments);


   if (File.Exists(attachments[0].ToString())) {
            File.Delete(attachments[0].ToString()); 
        }
```

Comment: Your `File.Close()` and `File.Dispose()` lines are wrong, they would not compile. You were right on the file getting locked, but not because of the `File.WriteAllBytes()` call, that method works as intended and does not keep a lock of the file. OP's problem was on the method `SendMail` but unfortunally he/she did not include that code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

you need to delete the file after "close" not before. As long as the close has not executed, the file will be in the stream loop and it counts as its own process and thus cannot be deleted until the file is closed. Hope this helps. Im guessing your close statement is below that code. Move it before the delete statment.

Comment: What close? `File. WriteAllBytes` doesn't leave any file handles or streams open. It's far more likely that `SendMail` opens a stream and forgets to close it

Comment: ok, my bad. I guess what I wanted to point out is that its 100% because some stream is open without closing it as that always counts as a process.